# Copy cells from specified column, removing duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I'm newbie in VBA, what I need to do is to copy rows from specified column into a column on the other worksheet, but I want to copy just one occurance of each word, for example

```
Column "F"
dog
dog
cat
dog
```

In the result I need to have new Worksheet called "Animals" with:

```
Column "A"    Column "B"
1             dog
2             cat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sub routine that will do exactly what you want: slap a list of unique elements in Sheet1 column F into column A of sheet2 and rename the sheet "animals". You could tweak this so that instead of it changing the name of sheet2 it can create a new sheet if you like.

```vb
Sub UniqueList()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim dictionary As Object
Set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Sheet1.Activate
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).row

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If Len(cells(i, "F")) <> 0 Then
        dictionary.Add cells(i, "F").Value, 1
    End If
Next

Sheet2.range("a1").Resize(dictionary.count).Value = _
Application.Transpose(dictionary.keys)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox dictionary.count & " unique cell(s) were found and copied."

End Sub
```

**How it works:** I use a dictionary file, which will automatically take out any dupes, then slap the list of entries into sheet2.

Comment: Runs without errors, prompts msg "xx unique cells were found and copied", but Sheet2 stays clear Sheet2

Comment: This might occur if you run the macro while on a different sheet. I tweaked the code so that this won't occur. It's also possible that Sheet 2 in your file is something different, so I removed the renaming part - please check the new code for functionality.

Comment: You're very welcome! Sorry the renaming the sheet part didn't work out. You can add a sheet2.name = "animals" at the end of the code and it should work. :)

Comment: The renaming part I need is a little bit complicated than I described here, but I dealt with that part by myself so it's fine ;)

Comment: @Issun: nice use of dictionaries (again!). Your solution is very clear and desserves a +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to do this in VBA at all?

If you just want to get a unique copy of your list, select the unsorted, non-unique column contents including the header, then hit the Advanced... button on the Sort and Filter pane of the Data ribbon. You can ask it to copy to another location and tick Unique records only.

Recording this activity and looking at the VBA, this is how it looks:

```
Range("A1:A4").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("B1"), Unique:=True
```

Comment: I've got a lot of .xls files to cope with so I need to have this process automated

Comment: @Jandrejc the single-line VBA in my answer should let you automate that for you nicely.

Comment: That one line will only take the range in A1:A4 and copy the unique elements to column B if I am not mistaken. What he wants is to take a column from one sheet and paste the unique elements onto a different sheet in column A.

Comment: Ah, and Excel will only let you copy filtered data to the currently-active sheet, so you'll have to copy it to a free column of your choice first, then use (automated) vanilla copy-paste to move it out to another sheet. Sorry, I just focused on getting the unique list.

Comment: And i'm wrong again... when recording the macro, the UI only lets you paste the unique cells into the active sheet, but editing the destination range in the VBA works a treat. Thanks Excel! ;-)

Comment: Actually, when you use the advanced filter in VBA it lets you copy to different sheet. Xav's answer is the fastest and most concise of all the answers and would work the best. It just needs to be made for the exact answer that the person is using, but the questioner should be able to do that on their own. To copy to a different sheet lets say that r1 is the range to copy to (on a specified sheet) so CopyToRange:=r1. Pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution:

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyNoDuplicates()
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim cell As Range, i As Long
Dim cAnimals As Collection
Set cAnimals = New Collection
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Find last used cell
    Set rLastCell = .Range("F65536").End(xlUp)
    'Parse every animal and put it in a collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In .Range("F2:F" & rLastCell.Row)
        cAnimals.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    For i = 1 To cAnimals.Count
        .Range("A" & i).Value = i
        .Range("B" & i).Value = cAnimals(i)
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel does this for you with a built-in function. While this code will uniquely sort the list for you, I bet the built-in function is a lot faster than using the VBA Collection class.

Comment: +1. Works for me! I took a slightly different approach (you know how i love the dictionary object :p) and decided not to put the numbers in like you did (which I can see how it can be interpreted that he wanted those). Good stuff as always, JMax ^^

Comment: If column contains numbers like: 4 5.5 it just skips the cell

Comment: try to add a `CStr` to convert the key (i edited my post). Anyway, if Issun answer works, keep it and use it!